# Cocos2d lock iPhone device orientation (with UIKit objects)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

In cocos2d I can successfully lock the orientation of the device using:

GAME_AUTOROTATION==kkGameAutorotationNone

But this doesn't rotate UiKit objects and I'm using a Gesture. Can I get the whole app to just go into landscape mode at launch and stay there (Ui components included)?

Answer (score 1):

You could edit the Info.plist file in order to add the UIInterfaceOrientation key with the appropriate value.

Check the following apple's how-to:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#codinghowtos/UserExperience/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

If your only problem is with the orientation of the gesture recognizer and the positions it returns, then simply apply `[CCDirector convertToGL:pos]` to any such position to convert it to the OpenGL coordinates cocos2d uses.

For example check out the code of the Kobold2D [KKInputGesture class](https://github.com/kobold2d/Kobold2D/blob/master/Kobold2D/__Kobold2D__/kobold2d/KKInputGesture.m).